# Accessing outer object from inner object

Tags: c++

Consider the following snippet:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>

class Foo {
private:
  struct Bar {
     void moo();
  };

  uint32_t meow;
  Bar      bar;
};

void Foo::Bar::moo() {
  auto foo = (Foo*) ((uint8_t*) this - offsetof(Foo, bar));
  foo->meow++;
}
```

Now, I'm understand that this snippet probably violates every rule that exists in the standard. But consider the embedded environment where you want to save as much RAM as possible, and you want to avoid storing any redundant pointers to enclosing structures.

Given that:

1. only one `Bar` field will be present in class `Foo`
2. no other `Bar` instances would ever be created (on i.e. on stack)
3. `Bar` cannot be copied or moved, and is accessed only via reference to `Foo` field.

Is it possible to access the enclosing instance in a more safe, well-defined and compliant way?

**Why Bar is actually needed?**

Because `Bar` is used to implement the interface, and instance is used to track which implementation has been called. Array has been omitted in original example for brevity.

```
struct Cow {
    virtual void moo() = 0;
};

struct Foo {
  constexpr static uint32_t N_COWS = 2;

  explicit Foo();

  struct CowImpl: public Cow {
    uint8_t idx;

    void moo() override;
  };

  CowImpl cows[N_COWS];
  void moo(uint8_t cowIndex);
};

Foo::Foo() {
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < N_COWS; i++) {
        cows[i].idx = i;
    }
}

void Foo::CowImpl::moo() {
  auto foo = (Foo*) ((uint8_t*) this - offsetof(Foo, cows) - idx * sizeof(CowImpl));
  foo->moo(idx);
}
```

Comment: Why not make `moo()` a method of `Foo` and forget about `Bar`?

Comment: `void moo(Foo& outer);`

Comment: "*you want to avoid storing any redundant pointers to enclosing structures*" - I don't think this is a good idea. Since `Bar` needs access to `Foo`, and there is only 1 `Bar` per `Foo`, and `Bar` is never created outside of `Foo`, then it makes sense for `Bar` to store a reference to its containing `Foo` so it can reuse that reference whenever it wants. Otherwise, you are putting the responsibility of `Foo` to always pass in a reference to itself whenever it needs to do something with `Bar`, and that is more redundant than just having `Bar` store a reference internally.

Comment: You're talking about "embedded environment". Could you precise the target platform & compiler ? I might have a 0 memory overhead solution for your 2nd snippet, but it works only on some platforms.

Comment: @VincentSaulue-Laborde arm-none-eabi-gcc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer might not work on all platforms, but to my knowledge should work on ARM.

#### Basic idea

Given the following base class:

```cpp
struct Cow {
    virtual void moo() = 0;
};
```

Depending on the target platform, the following 2 derived types *might* have the same size in memory:

```cpp
struct Cow_index : public Cow {
    uint8_t index;
    void moo() override;
};

struct Cow_ref : public Cow {
    Foo& owner;
    Cow_ref(Foo& o) : owner(o) {}
    void moo() override;
};

static_assert(sizeof(Cow_index) == sizeof(Cow_ref), "");
```

See [godbolt (demo)](https://godbolt.org/z/qda7Y56ds). The `static_assert` passes on `gcc/arm32` and `gcc/mips` with default settings, but fails on arduino. This is dependent on the target ABI, and the compiler's memory alignment settings.

#### Proposition

Assuming the above snippet work on your platform, I would rewrite the 2nd snippet from the question as follows:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iterator>

struct Cow {
    virtual void moo() = 0;
};

struct Foo {
    constexpr static std::int32_t N_COWS = 2;

    explicit Foo() {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N_COWS; ++i) {
            cows[i].owner = this;
        }
    }

    struct CowImpl: public Cow {
        Foo* owner;

        void moo() override {
            const std::ptrdiff_t index = std::distance(&owner->cows[0], this);
            assert(index >= 0 && index < N_COWS); // or throw, or std::terminate.
            owner->moo(index);
        }
    };

    CowImpl cows[N_COWS];
    void moo(std::uint8_t cowIndex);
};
```

- No memory overhead as shown in **Basic idea**.
- No `reinterpret_cast` or C-style cast.
- An `assert` checking the CowImpl belong to the right Foo (at this point, you shouldn't be in undefined behaviour yet).
- The only bit of pointer arithmetic is subtly hidden behind a `std::distance`.
- No warnings with gcc 12.2 `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`.

It could probably use more `const`, `private`, and `std::array` to be more compliant with modern C++ guidelines, but that's outside the scope of this question.

[Live demo (godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/e9b7oTGW6)

---

**Edit:**

The default copy/move constructors and copy/move assign of `Foo` in **Proposition** will have undesirable behaviour (and cause bugs). They should either be marked `= delete`, or be manually defined to set the correct `Foo::cows[*]::owner`.